# Is it possible to connect Salesforce and SQL Server on a local connection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce, odbc

I am trying to connect my local instance of SQL Server to Salesforce using a Devart ODBC. Each time I attempt to link the servers, I receive the error message below. I am not married to this solution so if you have other suggestions, please let me know.

[image: Error Message]

[image: Server Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to create a system DSN in windows called <<DATA_SOURCE>> that actually maps to the salesforce host, and supplies credentials. looks like you missed this step